# ASP.NET Core 1.1 web app loading error with Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a solution with Visual Studio 2017 RC, all worked not too bad but I closed the solution and re-opened it later and I cannot load the Web application project anymore, I have the error :

> An error occurred with the project.
>
> Value cannot be null.
>
> Paramater : key

[image]

The project targetd the framework **.NETCoreApp 1.1**.

This is the error I found on the log file :

```
=====================
12/01/2017 13:16:45
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: La valeur ne peut pas être null.
Nom du paramètre : key
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.EnsureNotFaultedTree(IProjectVersionedValue`1 appliedValue)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.<PublishTreeAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
---> (Exception interne #0) System.ArgumentNullException: La valeur ne peut pas être null.
Nom du paramètre : key
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.EnsureNotFaultedTree(IProjectVersionedValue`1 appliedValue)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.<PublishTreeAsync>d__66.MoveNext()<---

===================
```

The error translated in english :

```
=====================
12/01/2017 13:16:45
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or several errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null.
Parameter's name : key
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.EnsureNotFaultedTree(IProjectVersionedValue`1 appliedValue)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.<PublishTreeAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
---> (Exception interne #0) System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null.
Parameter's name : key
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.EnsureNotFaultedTree(IProjectVersionedValue`1 appliedValue)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.TreeService.<PublishTreeAsync>d__66.MoveNext()<---

===================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was post on the Visual Studio developer community : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/11125/visual-studio-2017-rc-unable-to-load-a-aspnet-core.html

So, this is the solution :

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete all *bin* and *obj* objects of your project
3. Re-open your solution, your .NETCoreApp 1.1 project will be correctly loaded
4. Add the NuGet package : *Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native*, version 1.5.0-beta2-24728

This manipulation fixes the problem.